# How to disable if same file is uploaded?

Tags: php, file, input, file-upload

I need to input 3 files at the same time, 
I'm wondering how NOT TO insert if the same file is uploaded at the same time. It is okay if its already in the db.
 
Example **sample.pdf** is already inserted in "warm_up" then the other input (drill1 and drill2) wont be able to upload **sample.pdf** file

I'm also thinking if it is possible if the file I inserted any on the "input file" won't show on the other inputs.

```
<input type="file" name="warm_up"  required/>                       
<input type="file" name="drill1"  required /> 
<input type="file" name="drill2"  required />
```

Comment: you could do some rudimentary processing client side using javascript using the `File` class - push each file into an array if it does not already exist ( warn if it does ) then submit the form. Further validation server side after.

Comment: You need to (and should) use the [`file_exists()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function, and then Google "check if a file exists php".

Comment: What I mean is - its okay if the same file name will be uploaded in the database. What I want is if the user entered the same file ex: sample.pdf and then upload it again in the other input file it wont be inserted on the db.

Comment: You may need javascript for this but there is a way to do in php, but that requires a bit of work. What Kuba wrote in a comment under the answer is the basics of doing it. They just didn't write it all out. You need to compare which it all boils down to.

Comment: However, you might face problems here with files of the same name, which stand to contain different data. Are you sure that is what you want to do here? Have you thought of that and compensated for it? Why not just rename them with a unique method?

Comment: Thinking if there is a method that the file I inserted any on the "input file" wont show up on other "input file"

Answer (score -2):

You can compare the size of the file name and extension after sending the form in php

Comment: Better to compare the actual file contents, or someone can trick the system by making a copy of the file with a different name.  (And if you meant comparing the size of the file, that can lead to problems with different files that happen to be the same size.)

Comment: I meant the if`if($size1 == $size2 && $name1 == $name2 && $ext1 == $enx2){something is wrong}`

Comment: Having an md5 hash for every file on the database, and searching to see if any of those match the md5 hash of the uploaded file is a pretty simple comparison of file content

Comment: Comparing size and name should handle *most* cases reasonably well, but it'll cause a problem if the user has files with the same name in different folders, and the files have different contents but happen to be the same size.  Better to check the actual file contents (e.g. by comparing hashes).